# Tab android content sometime gone or dissapear

Tags: android, tabs

I'm working on android tab right now, i was wondering why sometime content of my tab is gone,,by default android initializing and create 2 first tab content, i check by print the log in console, and when i click the third tab it will attach and initialize,, and sometimes when i clicked back in first tab or second tab, my content is gone like invisible or something, here my code

```
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(ArticleFragment.newInstanceFeatured(1, ArticleFragment.FEATURED_LATEST), ArticleFragment.FEATURED_LATEST.toUpperCase());
        adapter.addFragment(ArticleFragment.newInstanceFeatured(1, ArticleFragment.FEATURED_POPULAR), ArticleFragment.FEATURED_POPULAR.toUpperCase());
        adapter.addFragment(ArticleFragment.newInstanceFeatured(1, ArticleFragment.FEATURED_TRENDING), ArticleFragment.FEATURED_TRENDING.toUpperCase());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

here my adapter for the tab content

```
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

I have **Latest**, **Popular**, and **Trending** Tab, each tab contain recyclerview, i retrieve data from my API and put them on it.., i know my code is working perfectly i completely success to retrieve and set the list but sometime if I change tab from one to another it happen, like  the content gone or missing or something, I implement swipe refresh too, sometime i try to swipe to refreshing the data and the Recycler view back and sometime it given null value... i have no idea what i gonna do, i think it work in the process but i don't know why.. please if you have same experience i would love to hear it.. thanks...

Answer (score 0):

i found something, turns out it not tab but my recycler reinitialize each tab clicked,,,

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Comment: Weclome to SO. Please not that code only answers do not fulfill the standards of SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer